# Speed Dial for Safari for OS X

Tags: osx, safari

I am looking for a Safari for OS X extension with features similar to the following extensions:

[Speeddial2 for Chrome](https://speeddial2.com)

or

[Speed Dial for Firefox](http://speeddial.uworks.net)

It needs to have the following functions:

- **Multi tabbed (so i would have a separate tab for social sites and then a separate tab for finance related sites, for example)**
- Live update of thumbnails
- Drag and drop reordering
- Drag and drop addition of the new sites
- Open favourite sites with shortcuts

PS: Browser extension is preferable but other options are welcome too.